# how to create connection for microsoft analysis services

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

follow this process to Configuring HTTP Access to SQL Server Analysis Services

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2008/08/15/configuring-http-access-to-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-on-microsoft-windows-server-2008.aspx

I tried using the Basic Authentication or Windows authentication for http connectivity.

But while accessing it from management studio i take server name as

http:/localhost/c:/inetpub/wwwroot/olap/msmdpump.dll

But it gave the error.

The connection either timed out or was lost. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (System)

Can you explain how this could be solved? thanks

Comment: Which security settings did you configure in the IIS settings for the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For configuration HTTP access to SSAS follow Steps through link-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use `http:/localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll` instead of `http:/localhost/c:/inetpub/wwwroot/olap/msmdpump.dll`. The web server (IIS) exposes the `wwwroot` directory as its root.

Comment: I used also http:/localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll as server name. it gave same error.

Comment: The IIS service is running? What happens if you access `http://localhost/` in a browser?

Comment: yes IIS service is running. When i access http://localhost/ in a browser, it show content of folder c:\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: @user3132353 As I already had asked below your question: how did you configure the security settings for the IIS application? Furthermore: Which security settings are there for the cube that you try to access?

Comment: I select Window Authentication security setting for IIS application

Comment: I configured HTTP Access to SQL Server Analysis Services. Follow steps  through link -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx